# Publishing to Websphere Application Server

Tags: eclipse, websphere

When ever I am trying to deploy the application on the IBM websphere I am receiving the following error:

> "The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start.
>   The application contains validation errors. Correct the errors in the Problems view before publishing the application on the server. 
>   If you want to allow applications containing errors to be published on the server, enable the Allow applications containing errors to be published on a server check box (Windows > Preferences > Servers > WebSphere).
>   The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved"

There few suggestions to look into eclipse.ini file but it didn't help me much.

I appreciate your inputs.

Thank you in advance,
Lucky

Comment: 1. Did you try what is suggested? "Allow applications containing errors to be published on a server check box (Windows > Preferences > Servers > WebSphere)."
2. It seems you have build path errors

Answer (score 4):

In your Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> Server -> WebSphere Application Server and check the box that says "Allow applications containing errors to be published on a server."

note: your version of Websphere may vary than the one shown in my example screenshot. Also, please note that I am using Spring Tool Suite, but it is essentially Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should explain us what are those validation errors. Anyway, you can disable the validation from Window->Preferences. Then publish the application on the WAS. This could help if the errors are non-blocking (for example javascript or xml validation errors).